# How to mantain state of checkbox in listview even if the activity destroed in android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

In my app i have a list view.and each item of listview contains one textview and one checkbox.When i am clicking one of checkbox then it is checked now.But when i am going back from the activity to the previous activity this checkbox again becomes unchacked.I am using custom adapter for listview.So plz help me how to fix it.Thanx

Comment: When you come back to your Activity, Your Activity will again create newly so you need to store your checkbox value then you can use that to maintain the state of checkbox.

Comment: Based on my experience, getview seems to be triggered at the end and it was why 'onRestoreInstanceState()' and 'onConfigurationChanged()' could not make it as getview will reset my checkboxes invisible as initialization in the layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the state of the checkbox in SharedPreferences, as below. Refer to [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for details.

Saving state :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("checked", checkboxStatus);
editor.commit();
```

Retrieving state :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean checked = prefs.getBoolean("checked", false);
```

Comment: But i have bunch of listview items and coresponding checkbox.So how i can save this in shared preferences.

Comment: For example, by adding a unique tag to each element of the listview, and using that as the key (or part of the key) so your list adapter knows which preference to ask for when generating Views in getView.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a sqlite database and store the state of check box to it. then retrieve data when needed.